# Curl Commands parallel on two seperate shells

Tags: curl, udp

I am testing the download speed of a website with curl and want to run one with TCP and the other with UDP on two different VM´s. But I want to measure both of them at the same time so that I know how they are working when they are both operating on the same website. So now I want to know if there is a possabilty to run two curl commands on two VM´s parallel.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `curl` doesn't support UDP.

Comment: Apart from that, if you want to time it right, set a cron job on both machines to execute at the same time and make sure their system clocks are in sync. That should take care of it.